# Using INNER JOIN and MAX(), to return same row as MAX

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, max, inner-join

For some reason, I can't get this query to return the result that I'm looking for. I'll explain that after outlining the situation...

There are two tables, one for **players** and one for **matches**. Within each match, a player gets a rating (float/decimal) based on what position they played in. This rating may improve in one position, but could be different/better in others. Therefore, I want to be able to see the **MAX(rating)** and the **pos** that the max was obtained in, **alongside the players details**.

So, my idea was to do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   players 
       INNER JOIN(SELECT pid, 
                         Max(rating) AS a, 
                         pos 
                  FROM   matches 
                  GROUP  BY pid) b 
               ON b.pid = players.ypid 
WHERE  players.ytid = '2010591' 
   AND players.status = '1' 
ORDER  BY ypromdate ASC, 
          ydob ASC
```

This does return all of the player's details and the max rating, however if the player has played in multiple matches (hence the GROUP BY) then the first record is returned for the **pos**. For example, if player1 got a rating of 5 as a defender and then 6 as a forward, this query will return 6 defender

If more information is required, then I'm happy to provide!

Thanks in advance..feel like I've taken the query down the wrong route..

*Edit* to help answer questions posted:

> Software: MySQL
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
>
> Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.69

Sample data, cut down to save time:

> **Matches table**: id, matchid, matchdate, position, timeplayed, rating, pid
> (149, 77221704, '2013-08-12 15:00:00', 100, 90, 1.5, 143569504),
>
> (150, 77221705, '2013-09-12 15:00:00', 103, 90, 3, 143569504)
>
> **Players table**: pid, ytid, status
> (143569504, 2010591, 1)

Expected outcome:

> pid, ytid, status, pos, Max(rating)
> 143569504, 2010591, 1, 103, 3

Current outcome:

> pid, ytid, status, pos, Max(rating)
> 143569504, 2010591, 1, 100, 3

Comment: Some sample data and desired output would be helpful, also, what database are you using (MySQL,SQL Server 2008, etc)?

Comment: Its mysql, nothing else would allow selecting pos in group by subquery. And pos being there is the main reason of getting its wrong value.

Comment: See above for edit, hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
select yourfields (not all of them)
from players p join matches m on m.pid = p.pid
join (select pid, max(rating) maxrating
from matches
group by pid) temp  on p.pid = temp.pid and rating = maxrating
etc
```

Comment: That does exactly what I asked it to do, and I shall promptly be accepting and marking it up. One final request to boggle your mind..running this query gave me: Showing rows 0 - 16 ( 17 total, Query took 252.0127 sec). Is this lag in time down to my database structure or the query itself? and if it is the latter, can this be improved upon? My thanks for solving the problem though!